# Regex to split by tags

Tags: c#, regex

I have a textfile like:

```
<page>
Line 1
Hello World
<endpage>
<page>
Another page
<endpage>
```

Now I want to split this text at the `<page>` and `<endpage>`-tags. I tried it with the following regular expression:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<page>.*?<endpage>");
MatchCollection matchCollection = regex.Matches(text);
```

but this only works, if there's no linebreak between `<page>` and `<endpage>`. What is the correct regular expression to solve my problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/496680

Comment: @Steve - that doesn't really apply here.

Comment: @CuongLe - Why do you assume this is XML?

Comment: Why split by regex and not just simply search the string for `<page>` - if found, search for `<endpage>` starting from the last `<page>` position, then take the substring, then searching for `<page>` with offset beign the last `<endpage>` etc.?

Comment: @Oded maybe it doesn't, it rather depends on the semantics of the tags.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but why not use xml and the built in xml parsing?

Comment: @h2ooooooo - because that would be a lot more complicated?

Comment: @Jodrell because it's not XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to match multiple lines with `.*` you need to enable the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<page>.*?<endpage>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch. It works perfect :) I accept you answer in 11 minutes -.-

Answer (score 1):

By default, `.` does not match a newline character.  This means that your pattern would only match if everything occurred on the same line.

In order to make it match across multiple lines, you need `RegexOptions.Singleline` (the name is a bit confusing, but the idea is that the whole string is treated as a "single line", instead of going through and testing the regex on each line).